# Derive cost function and supply function from production function

Tags: microeconomics

Find the cost function and supply function for $Q = L^\frac{1}{3} + \ln K$. Note that the price of $Q$ is $P$, the price of $L$ is $w$ and the price of $K$ is $r$. $Q$, $L$, and $K$ are all traded in a perfectly competitive market. Is this a solvable problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem is solvable.

**Hint:**

1. To find the cost function you need to solve the following:
   $$\begin{align}
   \min_{K,L\geq 0} \quad & wL+rK \\
   \textrm{s.t.} \quad & f(L,K) \geq Q
   \end{align}$$

   The solution to the above gives the conditional input demand functions:
   $L^{c}(Q,w,r)$, $K^c(Q,w,r)$

   substituting the input demands into the objective of the above problem gives the cost function:  $\boxed{C(Q,w,r)=wL^{c}(Q,w,r)+rK^c(Q,w,r)}$
2. Using the cost function $C(Q,w,r)$ derived in *1.* we can solve the following problem to find the supply function for a competitive firm:
   $$\begin{align}
   \max_{Q\geq 0} \quad & p\cdot Q-C(Q,w,r) \\ \\
   \textrm{FOC:} \quad & p-C'(Q,w,r)\overset{set}{=}0\\
   \textrm{SOC:} \quad & -C''(Q,w,r)<0 \text{ or } \\ &C''(Q,w,r)>0
   \end{align}$$

   Assuming $\text{SOC}$ holds the supply function is given by: $\boxed{Q^s(p,w,r) \;\text{ s.t. }\; p=C'(Q^s(p,w,r),w,r)}$